# next-redux-wrapper Wrapper.getStaticProps not working with

Tags: redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

This is my backend controller, I am getting the rooms data

```
const allRooms = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res) => {

    const resPerPage = 4;

    const roomsCount = await Room.countDocuments();

    const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(Room.find(), req.query)
        .search()
        .filter()

    let rooms = await apiFeatures.query;
    let filteredRoomsCount = rooms.length;

    apiFeatures.pagination(resPerPage)
    rooms = await apiFeatures.query;

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        roomsCount,
        resPerPage,
        filteredRoomsCount,
        rooms
    })

})
```

This is my redux actions I am sending the payload and data

```
    export const getRooms = (req, currentPage = 1, location = '', guests, category) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {

        const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);

        let link = `${origin}/api/rooms?page=${currentPage}&location=${location}`

        if (guests) link = link.concat(`&guestCapacity=${guests}`)
        if (category) link = link.concat(`&category=${category}`)

        const { data } = await axios.get(link)

        dispatch({
            type: ALL_ROOMS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ALL_ROOMS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}
```

This is my reducer function, dispatching the room data

```
export const allRoomsReducer = (state = { rooms: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ALL_ROOMS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                rooms: action.payload.rooms
            }

        case ALL_ROOMS_FAIL:
            return {
                error: action.payload
            }

        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Here I want to get the data using wrapper.getStaticProps but I am getting an error, but when i am using wrapper.getServerSideProps I get the data.

```
 export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(store=> async ({ req, query, })  => {
  await store.dispatch(getRooms(req, query.page, query.location, query.guests, query.category))
})
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: cannot read page of undefined,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in `({ req, query, }) =>` , `query` is `undefined`.

Going by the [documentation of next](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation), the `context` object for `getStaticProps` has no property `query`. It is only available in `getServerSideProps`.

See also [this info](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-at-build-time):

> Only runs at build time
> Because getStaticProps runs at build time, it does not receive data that’s only available during request time, such as query parameters or HTTP headers as it generates static HTML.